# Problema con creación de objeto en una clase

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en todo lo referente a la programación orientada a objetos y perdido a la creación de clases externas ,ademas los objetos en la misma, ¿cual  es 
el metodo correcto?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class segundaClase {
private String ruta;




public segundaClase(String ruta) {
    super();
    this.ruta = ruta;
}

public String CrearFile() throws IOException {
    File file = new File(this.ruta);
    if (file.createNewFile())
    {
        System.out.println("File is created!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("File already exists.");
    }
    return ruta;
}

public void setRuta(String ruta) {
    this.ruta = ruta;

}

public void getEscribir() {

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);

}

public String getRuta() {
    return ruta;
} 



}
```

EL main este

```
import java.io.*;

   public class FileReader {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

   segundaClase crearArchivo = new 
segundaClase("C:\\Users\\cuenta\\Downloads\\Nuevotxt.txt");
   crearArchivo.CrearFile();


  }
 }
```

Al crear el objeto `fr` no puedo pasar por parámetro mi otro objeto creado `file`

Comment: no se entiende tu pregunta

Comment: no se muy bien como crear el objeto es otra clase que no sea la clase main e implementarlos adecuadamente. Se que me he explicado mal pero con un ejemplo poco practico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale dos cosillas, la primera es que creas los archivos file, pero no los retornas en el caso de getEscribir y no lo almacenas en el caso de cuando lo creas, así que cuando lo intentas llamar, no existe ningun dichero sobre el que crear...

La segunda es que por consenso las clases son en mayusculas

Prueba estas modificaciones, Saludos!!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SegundaClase {
  private String ruta;
  private File file




  public segundaClase(String ruta) {
      super();
      this.ruta = ruta;
  }

  public String CrearFile() throws IOException {
      this.file = new File(this.ruta);
      if (file.createNewFile())
      {
          System.out.println("File is created!");
      } else {
          System.out.println("File already exists.");
      }
      return ruta;
  }

  public void setRuta(String ruta) {
      this.ruta = ruta;
  }

  public FileReader getEscribir() {
      return new FileReader(this.file);
  }

  public String getRuta() {
      return ruta;
  } 



}
```

Comment: varias preguntas ¿la excepción seria adecuada ponerla al método? o ¿es mejor implementarla directamente en la clase? , ¿cual seria la forma mas adecuada de declarar el objeto?, de todas formas tu código me funciono!

Comment: No las excepciones suelen ponerse a los metodos, los constructores con excepciones pueden parecer mejor elección pero acaban siendo problematicas. Te recomiendo que generes excepciones en los metodos, los captures y en el caso que lo quieras reparar, modifiques la variables mediante los setters y lo vuelvas a ejecutar

Comment: Gracias, también doy por valida el código que pusiste